# cross-browser problem with input type submit

Tags: php, html, input, submit

I have a problem with a form that I made, it is working in Firefox but in IE and Chrome it doesnt! when I press the Submit button in **IE** and **Chrome** nothing happens! I didnt check this before because I didnt thought that I will have problems like this! I dont know what I am missing here! is there any known problem (bug)

the form:

```
    <div id="Formulari">
<div class="WraperForForm"> 
<form action="index.php?menu=rezervimet&submenu=rezervo" method="post">

<div class="elementsLabelBox">
        Emri:
</div>
<div class="elementsBox">
        <input type="text" id="emri" name="emri">
</div>

<div class="elementsLabelBox">
        Mbiemri:
</div>
<div class="elementsBox">
        <input type="text" id="mbiemri" name="mbiemri">
</div>

<div class="elementsLabelBox">
        Prej:
    </div>
<div class="elementsBox">
        <select class="selectDest" name="Prej" onChange="getState(this.value)">
            <option></option>
            '.funksionet::all_directions().'
        </select>
</div>

<div class="elementsLabelBox">
        Deri:
</div>
<div class="elementsBox">
        <div id="statediv"><select class="selectDest" name="deri">
            <option></option>
        </select></div>
</div>
<div class="elementsLabelBox">

            <form name="Data1Drejtim">
            <label for="data1drejtim">Data e nisjes:</label>
</div>
<div class="elementsBox">
            <input type="text" id="data1drejtim" name="data1drejtim">
            <script language="JavaScript">


    // whole calendar template can be redefined per individual calendar
    var A_CALTPL = {
        \'months\' : [\'Janar\', \'Shkurt\', \'Mars\', \'Prill\', \'Maj\', \'Qershor\', \'Korrik\', \'Gusht\', \'Shtator\', \'Tetor\', \'Nentor\', \'Dhjetor\'],
        \'weekdays\' : [\'Di\', \'He\', \'Ma\', \'Me\', \'Ej\', \'Pr\', \'Sh\'],
        \'yearscroll\': true,
        \'weekstart\': 0,
        \'centyear\'  : 70,
        \'imgpath\' : \'images/\'
    }

    new tcal ({
        // if referenced by ID then form name is not required
        \'controlname\': \'data1drejtim\'
    }, A_CALTPL);
    </script>

</div>
<!-- ___________________ RETURN DATE _____________________________________ -->
<div id="hideThis">
<div class="elementsLabelBox">
        <label for="dataKthyese">Data kthyese:</label>
</div>  

<div class="elementsBox">           
            <input type="text" id="dataKthyese" name="dataKthyese">
                <script language="JavaScript">


    // whole calendar template can be redefined per individual calendar
    var A_CALTPL = {
        \'months\' : [\'Janar\', \'Shkurt\', \'Mars\', \'Prill\', \'Maj\', \'Qershor\', \'Korrik\', \'Gusht\', \'Shtator\', \'Tetor\', \'Nentor\', \'Dhjetor\'],
        \'weekdays\' : [\'Di\', \'He\', \'Ma\', \'Me\', \'Ej\', \'Pr\', \'Sh\'],
        \'yearscroll\': true,
        \'weekstart\': 0,
        \'centyear\'  : 70,
        \'imgpath\' : \'images/\'
    }

    new tcal ({
        // if referenced by ID then form name is not required
        \'controlname\': \'dataKthyese\'
    }, A_CALTPL);
    </script>
            </form>
</div>
</div>  




<div class="elementsLabelBox">
    Persona:
</div>
<div class="elementsBox">
        <select name="persona">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
</div>
<!-- <tr>
    <td width="30" >Fëmij:</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" name="femij"></td>
</tr> -->

<div class="elementsBox">
</div>
<div class="elementsLabelBox">
</div>

<div class="elementsLabelBox">
        <label for="1drejtim">Një drejtim</label>
        <input type="radio" id="1drejtim" name="drejtimi"  value="një drejtim" onclick="toggleVisibility(\'hideThis\',0)">
<br/>
        <label for="1drejtim">Kthyese</label>
        <input type="radio" id="kthyese" name="drejtimi" checked="checked" value="kthyese"  onclick="toggleVisibility(\'hideThis\',1)">
</div>


    <input style="float:right;margin:15px 49px 0 0;" type="submit" value="Rezervo" name="rezervo" />


</form><!-- end of the reservation form-->
</div>
</div><!-- end of Formulari-->
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is this? `<form action="index.php?menu=rezervimet&submenu=rezervo" method="post">` -- query string is part of a GET request, but you want the form sent by POST. You can't mix, an HTTP request is of only one type. Put menu and submenu into hidden inputs.

Comment: Can I use this: <form action="" method="post"> because I want to be sent (post) to current page! I tried this but yet it doesnt work!

Comment: @Dan Altough you can't mix a http request. This is not wrong. The form is still sent via post but doing so sets the GET variables in some languages (ie: PHP)

Comment: @dan Yeah, that way he used works, i use it all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `<form>` tags in this document, and the one nested closest to the submit button has no action or method attributes. IE and Chrome are correct to do nothing since this form has no action to associate with submission.

Comment: Yes there is a form inside another one. They both need to have seperate actions. If there is a reason  for you to do that you can use JS to post desired form.

Comment: I fixed the problem and I would like to thank you for helping me.